# How to convert a list of keys and a list of value lists to a single list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of keys and a list of value lists.
What I need to do is to convert these two lists to a single list with dictionaries.

I have a key list:

```
keys = ['id','firstname','lastname']
```

My value list is like:

```
values = [[23,'abc','gef'],[24,'aabb','ppqq']]
```

The expected output is:

```
data = [{'id':23,'firstname':'abc','lastname':'gef'}, {'id':24,'firstname':'aabb','lastname':'ppqq'}]
```

I will be working with a large list as 'values' list. Is there any efficient 'pythonic' way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a simple list comprehension:

```
>>> keys = ['id','firstname','lastname']
>>> values = [[23,'abc','gef'],[24,'aabb','ppqq']]
>>> [dict(zip(keys, value)) for value in values]
[{'id': 23, 'firstname': 'abc', 'lastname': 'gef'}, {'id': 24, 'firstname': 'aabb', 'lastname': 'ppqq'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension.
[zip()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is to map the similar index of multiple containers so that they can be used just using as single entity.

```
keys = ['id','firstname','lastname']
value = [[23, 'abc', 'gef'], [24, 'aabb', 'ppqq']]
data = [{k:v for k,v in zip(keys,v)} for v in value ]
print(data)
```

O/P:

```
[{'id': 23, 'firstname': 'abc', 'lastname': 'gef'}, {'id': 24, 'firstname': 'aabb', 'lastname': 'ppqq'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

a one-liner would be `data = [{k:v for k, v in zip(keys, v)} for v in values]` which combines a list comp and dict comp

```
>>> keys =['id','name1','name2']
>>> values = [[23, 'a','g'],[24,'ab','cc']]
>>> data = [{k:v for k, v in zip(keys, v)} for v in values]
>>> data
[{'id': 23, 'name1': 'a', 'name2': 'g'}, {'id': 24, 'name1': 'ab', 'name2': 'cc'}]
```